# merging xts series, times not lining up

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I have two `xts` series I'm trying to merge:

ap1:

```
                ia       il
1997-01-01 12200000 11200000
1998-01-01 12500000 10600000
1999-01-01 12100000 10800000
2000-01-01 12300000 11200000
2001-01-01 11700000 11000000
```

apT:

```
               usa
1997-01-01 79537000
1998-01-01 80165000
1999-01-01 77386000
2000-01-01 79551000
2001-01-01 75702000
```

But after `merge(apT, ap1)`

it returns:

```
                usa       ia       il
1997-01-01 79537000       NA       NA
1997-01-01       NA 12200000 11200000
1998-01-01 80165000       NA       NA
1998-01-01       NA 12500000 10600000
1999-01-01 77386000       NA       NA
1999-01-01       NA 12100000 10800000
2000-01-01 79551000       NA       NA
2000-01-01       NA 12300000 11200000
2001-01-01 75702000       NA       NA
2001-01-01       NA 11700000 11000000
```

Why aren't the days lining up? I checked the timezones and they both return "America/New_York"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transferred from comments.  Likely the datetimes are slightly off in the two objects.  Use Date class instead of POSIXct to avoid that possibility.

Comment: To the person who suggested the edit that I rejected, I wasn't suggesting that POSIXct be used and then converted to Date. I was suggesting that Date be used *instead* of POSIXct right from the start.

Comment: Yes, this is likely the cause.  Seems related to [xts issue #191](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/issues/191).  Thoughts/comments would be appreciated!